# character for single quote

Tags: quotes, backticks

(backtick) and ' are two different characters for single quote.  I have a mysql script that shows the former two quote characters, if I change them to ', it breaks the syntax.
how do I type ` from the keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referring to the character commonly called a "backtick" (<kbd>`</kbd>).  It is *not* a single quote, although in some fonts it can look like one.  It has a completely different meaning in MySQL than a single quote, as it is used to escape table and column names, whereas the single quote is used to enclose data values.

It is at the top-left of your keyboard in all likelihood, often just to the left of the <kbd>1</kbd> key (as Dav pointed out below, on US keyboard layouts, it's the non-shift version of the tilde (<kbd>~</kbd>) key).

Comment: On U.S. keyboards, it's the non-shift version of the `~` key.