# phpmyadmin sql apostrophe not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

hey guys was hoping you could help me out,

Not sure if I always had this problem or if its new, in phpmyadmin in the sql tab, the apostrophe it recognizes is different from what i type, for example,

when i type, it is

```
SELECT * FROM 'table'
```

this gives me an error, so instead I have to like copy/paste the inverted commas of some prebuilt query so that it looks like

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
```

see how the apostrophes are different? any way I can fix this?

also, i have seen many queries on the web, and i think even queries i call from php dont require table names to have apostrophes. But when write it in phpmyadmin, I can do queries without table names having apostrophes?

thanks in advance.

Comment: does the ` not in your keyboard on top of tab?

Comment: I don't understand why many people keep table name as TABLE??

Comment: @islandmyth There's such a thing as different keyboard layouts. ;-)

Comment: @FahimParkar Probably just an example.

Comment: @Gnarfoz :) if he's lucky it should be there.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275127/character-for-single-quote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***In MYSQL, `table` is a reserved keyword. If you want to use reserved keywords in mysql in query, you have to enclose them in backtick(`).***

As `table` is reserved keyword you query ***should be***

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
```

Regarding **single quote (')**, in mysql, it represents string value.

```
SELECT *, 'table' FROM `table`;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/416e4/1)

Comment: +1 for demo in sqlfiddle

Comment: @barts : sqlfiddle is my best friend these days. I never test any mysql query on my PC machine. And its good to give demo on what we write so that OP and especially others can see how output is coming with respective query...

Comment: I didn't know this one up to now.  I only new jsfiddle, but its good to know as I am soon into a php/mysql project...

Comment: thanks, was literally  going mad over this for more than an hour :/....

Comment: not a problem. happy to help...

Answer (score 2):

You should only need to quote table names when they conflict with a reserved word.

Also:

```
` = Grave accent, or (because someone needed to invent a word) backtick
' = Apostrophe, or straight single quote
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need apostrophe on table name.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ` in cases that your table/field name is a reserve word eg:

```
SELECT `distinct`, myfields FROM mytable
```

note that distinct is an sql command so you need to put the `.

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
```

`table` here should be inside `.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different characters, the backtick  and the single quote. Table and column names can be surrounded by the backtick, strings can be surrounded by quotes. There is nothign to fix :D