# SQL query dosnt know variables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query some tables in my database using a simple dropdown in which the name of the tables are listed. the query has only one record result showing the name and age of the youngest institute registered in the database!

```
$table = $_GET['table'];
$query = "select max('$table'.est_year) as 'establish_year' from '$table' ";
```

I need to send the name of the table as variable to the querier php file. no matter the method is GET or POST in both ways when I put the variable name in the query statement, it gives the error:

> > "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.order) as 'last' from 'customers'' "

Comment: Are you sure the error message points at that line exactly? There's nothing like what the error message says in that query.

Comment: you've provided irrelevant piece-of-code

Comment: Are you sure your GET doesn't have any extra trailing spaces?

Comment: When I type the name of the tables manually, everything is ok and well. And I am sure there is nothing as space following the get value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrapping the table name in single quotes, which is not valid SQL (that's the syntax for strings, not table names). You should either not wrap the name at all or else wrap it in backticks (on the american keyboard layout, that's the key above <kbd>TAB</kbd>).

You should also not quote the alias `established_year`:

```
select max(`$table`.est_year) as establish_year from `$table`
```

**Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. [Fix this immediately!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**

#### Update (sql injection defense):

In this case the most appropriate action would likely be to validate the table name against a whitelist:

```
if (!in_array($table, array('allowed_table_1', '...'))) {
    die("Invalid table name");
}
```

Comment: do I need to use mysql_escape_string() or what ?

Comment: @rezasaberi: No for two reasons: 1) `mysql_escape_string` should never be used (`mysql_real_escape_string` has superseded it) and 2) it's a table name, where the rules are different. See the updated answer.

Comment: @Jon : How OP code is vulnerable to SQL Injection? And how mine is not preventing and yours is preventing?

Comment: @FahimParkar: Please see the comment under your own answer. Using a whitelist prevents injections because only a handful of known safe inputs will be accepted.

Answer (score -1):

**single quote (')**, in mysql, it represents string value.

```
SELECT *, 'table' FROM `table`;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/416e4/1)

So your query should be

```
$table = $_GET['table'];
$query = "select max($table.est_year) as 'establish_year' from $table ";
```

Also read old post, [phpmyadmin sql apostrophe not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155915/phpmyadmin-sql-apostrophe-not-working/11156024#11156024).

Also your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You can use something like this

```
//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection

function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

$firstName = clean($_POST['firstName']);
$lastName  = clean($_POST['lastName']);
.
.
.
```

Comment: -1: This code will not prevent SQL injection because `$table` will be a *table name*, not just any string. The quoting rules are different.

Comment: @Jon : Do you see `return mysql_real_escape_string($str);`??

Comment: I do. You have to realize that `mres` achieves nothing if the returned value is not enclosed in quotes, which in this case it cannot be because it is not a string.